# How do you get prometheus metrics from postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-operator

I have installed prometheus into my Kubernetes v1.17 KOPS cluster following [kube-prometheus](https://github.com/coreos/kube-prometheus), ensuring the `--authentication-token-webhook=true` and `--authorization-mode=Webhook` [prerequisets](https://github.com/coreos/kube-prometheus#prerequisites) are set and the [kube-prometheus/kube-prometheus-kops.libsonnet](https://github.com/coreos/kube-prometheus#cluster-creation-tools) configuration specified.

I have then installed Postgres using https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/postgresql using the supplied [values-production.yaml](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/postgresql/values-production.yaml) with the following set:

```
metrics:
  enabled: true
  # resources: {}
  service:
    type: ClusterIP
    annotations:
      prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
      prometheus.io/port: "9187"
    loadBalancerIP:
  serviceMonitor:
    enabled: true
    namespace: monitoring
    interval: 30s
    scrapeTimeout: 10s
```

Both services are up and working, but prometheus doesn't discover any metrics from Postgres.
The logs on the `metrics` container on my postgres pods have no errors, and neither do any of the pods in the `monitoring` namespace.
*What additional steps are required to have the Postgres metrics exporter reach Prometheus?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to update ClusterRole for Prometheus. By default, it hasn't permissions to retrieve a list of pods, services, and endpoints from non-monitoring namespace.

In my system the original ClusterRole was:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: prometheus-k8s
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - nodes/metrics
  verbs:
  - get
- nonResourceURLs:
  - /metrics
  verbs:
  - get
```

I've changed it to:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: prometheus-k8s
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - nodes/metrics
  - services
  - endpoints
  - pods
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- nonResourceURLs:
  - /metrics
  verbs:
  - get
```

After those changes, Postgres metrics will be available for Prometheus.